# Socket Using 'AF_BLUETOOTH' on Windows

Tags: python, windows, sockets, bluetooth

To put you all in the perspective, I have a Raspberry Pi 4, I want to use it as a (python socket) server and on the client side, I will use my Computer.
The problem is when I try to execute a program using AF_BLUETOOTH on windows (10) , it always says that there is no thing called AF_BLUETOOTH.
I also searched many forums and I saw that AF_BLUETOOTH is not supported by windows 10's python (3.8).
I am asking for confirmation of this information because I wasted a lot of my time trying to make it work...

```py
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH,socket.SOCK_RAW,socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
```

This is my work after reading the documentation, I couldn't find any good tutorial on the internet about this topic.

Thank you.

Comment: I know nothing about Python sockets but Bluetooth with WinSock must be used with AF_BTH and SOCK_STREAM.

Comment: I just rechecked, It is "AF_BLUETOOTH" (official python documentation). I'll consider working with Winsock ,as the client, as an option.